# Issues with jQuery and TinyMCE rich text editor?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm experimenting with the Tiny MCE editor. We also use jQuery, and I noticed that the standard Tiny MCE install includes a file called `tiny_mce_jquery.js`. Can anyone enlighten me as to what that's for? Oddly, I can't find anything about it online. Should I reference it in addition to the standard Tiny MCE script, or instead of? Does it provide anything additional or just avoid incompatibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [changelog](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/changelog.txt) I see this:

```
Version 3.0a3 (2007-11-13)
Added new experimental jQuery and Prototype framework adapters to the 
development package.
```

My guess its so you can use jquery inside of tinymce framework. Some [talk](http://ajaxian.com/archives/tinymce-3-first-look) has been going on to converting TinyMCE to use jquery but I believe nothing has been done in that space. Instead, people have focused on creating their [own solutions](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/2007-09-11-1/) that certainly do not match the power of TinyMCE

To answer your question, you do not need to reference it with the standard install unless you want to write a TinyMCE plugin using some jquery functions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is the tiny mce script to be used if you already have jquery loaded to replace the standard mce script. You do not need both.

I found this comment in their developer forums [here](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=28712)

> We have added some adapters to the API
>   so TinyMCE can use the jQuery API to
>   reduce it's size but this is currently
>   experimental and I haven't had the
>   time to play with it since we are now
>   focusing on stability for the core
>   API. TinyMCE will remain library
>   independent but that doesn't mean that
>   we can't still use other libraries as
>   an optional runtime for the core.